# Unable to use service name for load balancer in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to use service name in my application to redirect to the correct pods in kubernetes.

The pods of type `NodePort` is working properly. (i.e. `app1.qa.svc` does redirects me to the correct application.

However it does not work on type `LoadBalancer`. Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Error:

I am getting a `java.net.UnknownHostException: app4.qa.svc`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating this?  Is the `app4` service actually connected to some pods?  Where is the client running (in another pod)?  What error do you get?  (`LoadBalancer` vs. other service types shouldn't make a difference for communication within the cluster.)

Comment: I am getting a java.net.UnknownHostException: `app4.qa.svc`